# Is it better to store multiple values in one attribute as an array, or create another table for it?

Tags: database, core-data

I'm building an app the attach multiple pictures to a recording. Hence, there is a "Recordings" entity with attributes "Name" and "URL". I want to attach multiple images to one recording.

1. So do I add another attribute "images" and store array of images? If yes, how is that possible?
2. Or do I create another Entity that has attributes "Image" and "RecordingID" that has all images of all recordings and each image is connected to it's recording with with the recording ID? If yes, how do I create a unique ID for the recordings?

Please answer which one is better performance wise, and with your choice explain its associated question.

Comment: When you ask "which one is better performance wise" the only right answer is: try both and compare.

Comment: @alfasin If I knew how I would have. I have a question for each methods.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use the data, as always.

If you use an array of images, Core Data will load all of them as soon as you need one of them. You'll either have every image in memory at the same time, or none of them. If you'll always use all of the images at the same time, this might be OK.

If you use a separate entity, you can load individual images when you need them. It's slightly more complex but can reduce memory requirements. It also makes more sense if you decide you need more metadata for each image, for example a creation date.

In both cases you'll be better off saving the image to a file and putting just the filename in your persistent store. It's usually best to keep binary blobs like images and sounds out of Core Data. Binary is OK if you know the value will be very small, but images can potentially be quite large.

I'm not sure why you want a unique ID in the second case where you don't use one in the first case. If you need a unique ID for some reason, the `UUID` class is a convenient way to generate one.